# NodeJS testing HTTPS server with supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, certificate, supertest

I read about [supertest](https://npmjs.org/package/supertest). I managed to test two of my routes:

```
it('notAuthorized', function (done) {
    request.agent(server)
        .get('/notAuthorized')
        .expect('Content-Type', /html/)
        .expect(200)
        .expect(/Not authorized!/)
        .end(done)
})

it('redirect', function (done) {
    request.agent(server)
        .get('/no-valid-route')
        .expect('Content-Type', /plain/)
        .expect(302)
        .expect('Location', '/notAuthorized')
        .expect(/Moved Temporarily/)
        .end(done)
})
```

However, the problem starts when I want to access my other pages, those I need to register for. I found this solution for a regular registration:

```
describe('When logged in', function () {
    before(function (done) {
        // login the user
        agent
            .post('/users/session')
            .field('email', 'foobar@example.com')
            .field('password', 'foobar')
            .end(done)
    })

    // ...
})
```

In my application I register with a certificate. Can I somehow configure the test with my certificate? Changing my https options doesn't work either:

```
///////////////////
// https options
var options = {
    // ...
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};
```

I assume it is because of my middle ware I use in *every* of my routes:

```
 exports.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next){
    if(req.client.authorized) {
        // user authorized
        if(!req.session.user) {
            // set user session
            var cert = req.connection.getPeerCertificate().subject;
        // ..
```

```
// profile
app.get("/profile", mw.isAuthenticated, profileController.getProfile);

// user
app.get("/users", mw.isAuthenticated, userController.getUsers);

// chat
app.get("/chat", mw.isAuthenticated, chatController.getChat);
```

**Question:**

- is there anyway I can configure the agent with my certificate?
- should I maybe overthink the design of using the `isAuthenticated` middle ware in every route?
- can I somehow change the cookie object of supertest's agent?

If I could set the req object like the following snippet, I'd probably have a solution.

```
    req : {
        client : {
            authorized : true
        },
        connection :{
            getPeerCertificate : function(){
                this.subject = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you able to solve that by any chance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you have to monkey patch supertest's TestAgent class, superagent's Agent class, and superagent's 'request' export from lib/node/index.js.

Superagent is only designed to track the CA associated with a server, and as far as I can tell supertest doesn't even support that. The underlying request is actually made in index.js, and there's no API hook into any of the cert or key options you need to pass.